# Как мне корректно записать на файл, и считать с файла информацию

Tags: c++, struct, fstream

```
   struct bank 
{
    client* arr;
    unsigned int number_of_client = 0;
    string name;
    unsigned int annual_percentage;
};

struct country
{
    string name;
    unsigned int number_of_banks = 0;
    bank* arr;
};


struct client
{
    string name;
    unsigned int sum_contribution;
    string address;
};

 void keepFile(fstream& file,country*& arr,int number_of_country) {
        file.close();
        file.open("information.txt", ios::out | ios::in);
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_country; i++)
        {
            file.write((char*)&arr[i], sizeof(arr[i]));
        }
    }

    void giveInformation(fstream& file, country*& arr, int number_of_country) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_country; i++) {
            country buffer;
            file.read((char*)&buffer, sizeof(arr[i]));
            cout << "Страна " << buffer.name << endl << "количество банков в стране" << buffer.number_of_banks << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].number_of_banks; j++)
            {
                cout << "Банк " << buffer.arr[j].name << endl;
                for (int n = 0; n < buffer.arr[j].number_of_client; n++)
                {
                    cout << buffer.arr[j].arr[n].name << " " << buffer.arr[j].arr[n].address << buffer.arr[j].arr[n].sum_contribution;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: и какую информацию вам нужно записать и считать из файла?

Comment: страна -> имя банка , годовой процент -> клиент (имя , место жительство, взнос) и так с каждой страной

Comment: у меня в main есть масив country

Comment: Сериализуйте в json или xml и запишите в файл

Comment: спасибо , но я навичок , можно что-то попроще? или хоть пример хороший

Comment: вы удивитесь, но это и есть самый простой вариант. Смотрите: чтобы записать что-то в файл много ума не нужно - просто берете и побайтово записываете. Но как считывать? Если данные : это структура с константным размером, то это можно считать в такую же структуру, но если нет... Вам придется как-то это дело сериализовавать. Можно в бинарном формате, но он не читаем, поэтому если что то пойдёт не так сложно будет понять в чем проблема. Так что лучше использовать человеко-читаемый формат (если не собираетесь сохранять двоичные данные). И чтобы не изобретать свой - используйте уже готовый